# how to hide the row after jquery dialog confirmation

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I have a @Html.Actionlink (....) on a table. And I am showing a jquery dialog for the confirmation.
Everything works fine.
BUT I want to hide the row after user clicks 'continue' and if the link action return 'true'.

i am using following jquery code.

```
var unapproveLinkObj;
    // delete Link
    $('.unapprove-link').click(function () {
        unapproveLinkObj = $(this);  //for future use
        $('#unapprove-dialog').dialog('open');
        return false; // prevents the default behaviour
    });

    $('#unapprove-dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false, width: 400, resizable: false, modal: true, 
        buttons: {
            "Continue": function () {
                $.post(unapproveLinkObj[0].href, function (data) {  //Post to action
                    if (data == '<%= Boolean.TrueString %>') {

                      // I want to hide the row here.....

                    }
                    else {
                        //Display Error
                    }
                });
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            "Cancel": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
```

is there any way that i can refresh the page or may be just hide the row without refreshing..??

EDIT: Here is the Html

```
 @foreach (var i in Model)
{
    <tr class="grtr">
        <td>@i.CustomerName</td>
        <td>@i.BranchName
        <br />
        @i.Address
        </td>

        <td>@i.PostCode</td>
        <td>@i.City</td>
        <td>@i.Telephone</td>


            @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(i.Latitude))
            {
                <td>Yes</td>
            }
            else
            {
                <td>No</td>
            }
            @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(i.Longitude))
            {
                <td>Yes</td>
            }
            else
            {
                <td>No</td>
            }

        <td>@i.IsClaimed</td>
        <td>@Html.ActionLink("Approve", "Approve", "Location", new { id = @i.ID }, new 
       {
           @class="unapprove-link"

       })</td>
        <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Location", new { id = @i.ID }, new {@class="delete-link"})

       </td>
        <td>Map</td>
    </tr>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, your link is inside a `<td>` and you want to hide that row, which contain that td.. and you are storing your anchor object in `unapproveLinkObj`

so, hiding that row, which contains the `unapproveLinkObj` object. you can try

```
unapproveLinkObj.parents('tr').hide();
```

or if want to refresh the page, you can try

```
location.reload();
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for reply. None of this works !! am i doing wrong somewhere else?? do you need to see some more of code?

Comment: yes, can you post the generated html? and what `data` is returning on continue click?

Comment: can you check what `data` is returning? is it returning "True" or something else?

Comment: I think, casing can be a problem try this `if (data.toString().toLowerCase() == '<%= Boolean.TrueString %>'.toLowerCase()) {`

Answer (score 0):

Considering it comes within the condition below if there is no error when the user clicks `continue` try

```
if (data == '<%= Boolean.TrueString %>') {

       // I want to hide the row here.....
       $("table").hide(); // table is the id or class to access the table contents    

}
```

Comment: No it dosen't work. Though the response is 'True'. It seems nothing is working in the if(data==true){}...not even an 'alert(msg)'

Comment: Is it not coming within your condition? If not then you will have to re-check your condition. May be you are missing something or just try doing `if (data == 'true')` if its coming within the condition when there is no error. Can you post your `json` response if possible? Try simple `console.log('true')` and check if its working when true and if not then you might have done the wrong checking.

Comment: Well..if(data=='True') works...i dont know whats wrong with '<%= Boolean.TrueString %>' !! thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (data == '<%= Boolean.TrueString %>') {

       // I want to hide the row here.....
       $(".grtr").hide(); // access the row contents    

}
```